# Is there any way to create a new flutter project with upgraded gradle version?

Tags: gradle, flutter

I am using android studio for flutter project. Every time when I create flutter android studio says a new gradle version is available. So then I have to change it manually to new version. The problem is when I try to run app , it will download to new version. If I do not change it some plugins gives an error work with the old version.
This my *build.gradle* file.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' //here I have to change it to 3.5.1
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}...
```

I tried to upgrade flutter,dart,android studio,gradle. But it does not work. If I create a new android project , it was created with new version.  So how to create a new flutter project with upgraded gradle version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The Gradle version is hard coded to [flutter app's template](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app_shared/android.tmpl/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) (the same for the [kotlin version](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app_shared/android-kotlin.tmpl/build.gradle)). Typically a flutter version is also not guaranteed to be compatible with the *latest* gradle version, so maybe stick with the version from the template until you are sure it's compatible.

Comment: Broken link "flutter app's template"

Comment: @RukshanJS you are right, it looks like the grade version is no longer hard coded  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app_shared/android.tmpl/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.tmpl

Answer (score 0):

try `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.2` on the terminal.